# Why does the lighting on this object not work properly? Imported obj

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, lighting

As you can see, the sun is pointing at it from a direction, and the light is on the other side?
I exported an OBJ from Daz3d and then imported it into blender. Even when I remove the material, the pink, it still doesn't work. Other objects in the scene receive light properly. What is going on and how do I fix it?
[image]

Comment: maybe a problem of normals? try to recalculate or clear custom split normals data?

Comment: Clear custom split normals data worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a split normals problem that happens with some imported objects, go into the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data*